Quantile "survival rate" of random walks wakers between partitions
I'm working on a problem that involves analyzing the "survival rate" in a given quantile in a two-period random walk simulation. Let quantile=0.5, then the setup is as follows:

Generate N random walkers, each taking n steps per period.
For the first period, sum the steps for each walker (final position on a path) and identify the walkers who are above the median of these final positions of the first period.
For the second period, sum the steps for each walker and check which
of the walkers identified step 2 (i.e. those above the median in the
first period) are above the median overall.
The "survival rate" is the percentage walkers above the median in the first period that are also above median in the second period.

My simulations (1000 walkers, 1000 steps) consistently show the survival rate to be around 48%, rather than the 50% I would have expected intuitively. Is it just a matter of gamma distribution of medians vs normal, and 1000 walkers/1000 steps is not large enough for it to approach N?
Does anyone have insights on how to approach this problem from a theoretical perspective? I feel like I'm missing a key insight about how the selection process in the first period interacts with the median comparison in the second period.
As a reference, here is the Python code used for the simulations:
import numpy as np


def simulate_walks_and_analyze_quantile_survival(
    n_walkers: int = 1000,
    n_steps_total: int = 1000,
    relative_split_point_walk: float = 0.5,
    quantile: float = 0.5,
    random_state: np.random.RandomState = None,
):
    """
    Simulates random walks and analyzes the 'quantile survival rate' across two periods.

    Args:
        n_walkers: number of random walks to simulate
        n_steps_total: total number of steps in each walk
        relative_split_point_walk: relative point at which to split the walks into two
            periods (S1 and S2). Will be rounded to the nearest integer.

    Returns:
    survival_rate: percentage of walkers above median in S1 that stayed
        above median in S2.

    """
    if random_state is None:
        random_state = np.random.RandomState()

    # Generate random walks (1 for up, -1 for down)
    walks = random_state.choice([-1, 1], size=(n_walkers, n_steps_total))

    # Split into two periods
    split_point = int(n_steps_total * relative_split_point_walk)
    first_period = walks[:, :split_point]
    second_period = walks[:, split_point:]

    # Calculate cumulative positions at end of each period
    first_period_final = np.sum(first_period, axis=1)
    second_period_final = np.sum(second_period, axis=1)

    # Find walkers above median in first period
    first_period_quantile_value = np.quantile(first_period_final, quantile)
    walker_wins_first_period = first_period_final > first_period_quantile_value
    first_period_winners = np.where(walker_wins_first_period)[0]
    n_first_period_winners = np.sum(walker_wins_first_period)

    # Find how many of these walkers remain above median in second period
    second_period_quantile_value = np.quantile(second_period_final, quantile)
    n_first_period_winners_that_remain_winners = np.sum(
        second_period_final[first_period_winners] > second_period_quantile_value
    )

    return n_first_period_winners_that_remain_winners / n_first_period_winners


